# Pandas: How to plot a barchar with dataframes with labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
             timestamp      objectId  result
0  2015-11-24 09:00:00        Stress       3
1  2015-11-24 09:00:00  Productivity       0
2  2015-11-24 09:00:00     Abilities       4
3  2015-11-24 09:00:00     Challenge       0
4  2015-11-24 10:00:00  Productivity      87
5  2015-11-24 10:00:00     Abilities      84
6  2015-11-24 10:00:00     Challenge      58
7  2015-11-24 10:00:00        Stress      25
8  2015-11-24 11:00:00  Productivity      93
9  2015-11-24 11:00:00     Abilities      93
10 2015-11-24 11:00:00     Challenge      93
11 2015-11-24 11:00:00        Stress      19
12 2015-11-24 12:00:00     Challenge      90
13 2015-11-24 12:00:00     Abilities      96
14 2015-11-24 12:00:00        Stress      94
15 2015-11-24 12:00:00  Productivity      88
16 2015-11-24 13:00:00  Productivity      12
17 2015-11-24 13:00:00     Challenge      17
18 2015-11-24 13:00:00     Abilities      89
19 2015-11-24 13:00:00        Stress      13
```

I would like to achieve a barchart like the following [image: Picture taken from here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html]
Where instead of `a,b,c,d` there would be the labels in the column `ObjectID` the y-axis should correspond to the column `result` and x-axis should be the values grouped of the column `timestamp`.

I tried several things but nothing worked. This was the closest, but the `plot()` method doesn't take any customisation via parameters (e.g. `kind='bar'` doesn't work).

```
groups = df.groupby('objectId')
sgb = groups['result']
sgb.plot()
```

Any other idea?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to plot *exactly*? Because the figure you show does not seem to be related to the data you show. What should be in different colors, by which variable should the bars be grouped?

Comment: Hello joris, thank you for your answer. I edited my question. I hope the question is clear enough now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @NaderHisham is a very easy solution!
But just as a reference, if you for some reason cannot use seaborn, this is a pure pandas/matplotlib solution:

You need to reshape your data, so the different objectIds becomes the columns:

```
In [20]: df.set_index(['timestamp', 'objectId'])['result'].unstack()
Out[20]:
objectId   Abilities  Challenge  Productivity  Stress
timestamp
09:00:00           4          0             0       3
10:00:00          84         58            87      25
11:00:00          93         93            93      19
12:00:00          96         90            88      94
13:00:00          89         17            12      13
```

If you make a bar plot of this, you get the desired result:

```
In [24]: df.set_index(['timestamp', 'objectId'])['result'].unstack().plot(kind='bar')
Out[24]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc44a5c0>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much you answered perfectly my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
import seaborn as sns

In [36]:
df.timestamp = df.timestamp.factorize()[0]

In [39]:
df.objectId = df.objectId.map({'Stress' : 'a' , 'Productivity' : 'b' , 'Abilities' : 'c' , 'Challenge' : 'd'})

In [41]:
df
Out[41]:
   timestamp    objectId    result
0       0           a           3
1       0           b           0
2       0           c           4
3       0           d           0
4       1           b           87
5       1           c           84
6       1           d           58
7       1           a           25
8       2           b           93
9       2           c           93
10      2           d           93
11      2           a           19
12      3           d           90
13      3           c           96
14      3           a           94
15      3           b           88
16      4           b           12
17      4           d           17
18      4           c           89
19      4           a           13

In [40]:
sns.barplot(x = 'timestamp' , y = 'result' , hue = 'objectId' , data = df );
```

[image]

Comment: You're answer is very good. Thanks, but the solution that joris gave is also really valid.